# error my coding : The method setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){}) is undefined for the type RadioButton

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Help me my problem : The method setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){}) is undefined for the type RadioButton

my coding :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> pil3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, pert1);
pil3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
c.setAdapter(pil3);
c.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
{
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, 
         View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) 
         {
              index = c.getSelectedItemPosition();        
         }
         public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}
});
```

Comment: please format your code

Comment: im beginner pleasse help me

Comment: you have email pleasee

Comment: sterling pleassss help me , you have email ?

Comment: what is c here in your code. Is it radioButton or spinner ?

Comment: ya c is my code , radio button brother . do you have email brother .? i will my code send an email to you.?